# L attached before class name in enterprise web application in java Netbeans "wrong class path"

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans, enterprise, facade

I'm working with Enterprise web Application(java) in netbeans IDE first time so thats why i'm facing some problems. i created it and build connection with database. then created page and run. it is working fine but when i import class in servlet then it gives error

```
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

type Status report

    messageNot Found

    descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

    GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0
```

i import following
 import week10.ejb.UserFacadeLocal;

server message is

```
SEVERE:   `Class [ Lweek10/ejb/UserFacadeLocal; ] not found. Error while loading [ class week10.servlets.LoginController ]`
```

this class exist in week10.ejb package name in Week10Lab-ejb directory structure. while servlet exist in webPages folder under week10Lab-war directory.

so how this problem can be fixed either i have to add any jar file or it can be fixed by fixing class path? i checked some tutorial over internet but got same way as i'm doing then i searched it out over this site and found L value attached before class name but there was also not any answer.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your path of class `Lweek10/ejb/UserFacadeLocal` is correct?

Comment: this "L" is problem which is attached before week10, path should be without this L , but compiler attach this L before week10. so that why i think it gives error, But i don't know how to deal with it

Comment: No, that is simply a way that Java internally marks type names. The `L` is not the reason for the problem. The class is probably not in your classpath.

Comment: then how i can include that